# WebGL - IE crashing when drawing Triangles AND Lines (in IE11)

Tags: internet-explorer, opengl-es, webgl, internet-explorer-11

**Details**

- I can draw objects with Triangle strips just fine.
- I can draw objects with Line strips just fine.

**Problem**

- I'm unable to draw a combination of triangles (triangle strips) AND lines (line strips). Drawing both causes a crash (IE 11+).

**Question**

> Is this a known issue with IE11 (i.e. experimental-webgl)?
>   Can anybody seen similar crashing?

Comment: Does this happen in other browsers?

Comment: Not sure. I'll have to modify my test to support Firefox.

Comment: My application does not appear to support Firefox at all (not because of WebGL, but because of other unsupported things... which i need to definitely work on).